# Definition of semialgebra of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Somewhere (in some book) I have read and added to my notes following definition:

> Given a set $X$ a **semi-algebra** is a subset $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that
>
> 1. $X\in\mathcal{S}$;
> 2. for all $A,B\in\mathcal{S}$, then $A\cap B\in\mathcal{S}$; and
> 3. for all $A\in\mathcal{S}$, then there are finitely many $A_k\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $A^C=\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$ with disjoint union.

I can't find anything about it using search engines, thus the defined object must have some other, more official, name. Any idea?

Comment: semi-algebra is a pretty common name and was asked here often before, e.g. check:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256606/question-about-definition-of-semi-algebra
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135203/question-about-the-definition-of-a-semialgebra

or german wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebra (unfortunately I couldn't find an english entry)

Comment: See [Semi-ring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Semiring_of_sets).

Comment: @AaronLenz My comment was automatically generated by MSE.  Gono provided the link, and you seemed to assert that the link answered your question.  As such, I flagged this question as a duplicate, at which point the comment was automatically generated.

Answer (score 2):

On Wikipedia it's called a [semiring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Semiring_of_sets) also in my measure theory texts, though the Germans seem to prefer [Semialgebra](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebra), which why your surname (Lenz) might be the reason you come at it from this name.